# Vertically align text in table cell with image floated to the left?

Tags: html, css, image, html-table, vertical-alignment

The html:

```
<td>
    <img>
    text here
</td>
```

The css:

```
td img{
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

I want the picture to be floated to the left within the cell, and the text to be vertically-aligned to the middle. Without the picture there, the text is automatically vertically aligned to the middle, but with the picture there I can't seem to change the vertical alignment of the text.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you want the text below or to the right of the image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the height of the image itself you can use the line-height property.

```
<td style="line-height: 50px;">
    <img>Text text text
</td>
```

This should force the text to be displayed in the center of the line-height.

Comment: I've used this method many times! Wish I had thought of this first.

Comment: @matthewpavkov - I only thought of it because I've often been peeved about image alignment now that using `align="middle"` is deprecated in the image tag.

Comment: @dmnc: True, but that's also a condition I assumed from the context of the question. Nothing from OP's question indicated a request for a multi-line or universal solution, and this obviously assisted him/her.  I must have missed your answer below.

Comment: @JoelEtherton Please, it was not an attack. It's a caveat that is useful for people to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `vertical-align:middle;` in the CSS for the `img`. You may also want to consider setting that image as a background to that table cell, as you may have cross-browser issues regardless of how you position everything (setting the image as a background would avoid this).

Comment: @dmr for this to work you'll need to remove the `float: left;` and `display: block;`.

Answer (score 0):

Using **line-height** to vertically align text next to an image within a table cell onl**y works if you have one line of text.  The next line of text will be (as in the example above) 50px below the first line of text.**

Setting the **image as backgroun**d also does not work unless you set a margin within the cell = to the width of the image on whichever side you want the image to align.